# Web Scraping | Beautiful Soup | Parsing Tables

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are some great threads on this (some of which have helped me get to this point), but I can't seem to figure out why my program isn't working.

**Problem**: The program works but it only seems to be returning the first row when it should be looping through all the table rows.

I am using Python 3.5

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/year/2006"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = []

for table_row in soup.select("table"):
    cells = table_row.find_all(['td'])
    release_date = cells[0].text.strip()
    movie_name = cells[2].text.strip()
    genre_name = cells[3].text.strip()
    production_budget = cells[4].text.strip()
    box_office = cells[5].text.strip()
    movie = {"Release_Date" : release_date, 
             "Movie_Name" : movie_name, 
             "Genre" : genre_name, 
             "Production_Budget" : production_budget, 
             "Box_Office" : box_office}
    data.append(movie)
    print (release_date, movie_name, genre_name, production_budget, box_office)
```

This returns the ***January, 2006 BloodRayne Action $25,000,000 $2,405,420*** which is correct, but I need all the other rows in the table.

If this problem is easy to solve, getting this into a Pandas DataFrame would be the next step (but not necessary in the response).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) with some data cleaning:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/year/2006', header=0)[0]
df = df.dropna(how='all')
df['Release Date'] = df['Release Date'].ffill()
print (df.head())
    Release Date          Movie   Genre ProductionBudget  \
0  January, 2006            NaN     NaN              NaN   
1      January 6     BloodRayne  Action      $25,000,000   
2      January 6       Fateless   Drama      $12,000,000   
3      January 6  Grandma's Boy  Comedy       $5,000,000   
4      January 6         Hostel  Horror       $4,800,000   

  DomesticBox Officeto Date  Trailer  
0                       NaN      NaN  
1                $2,405,420      NaN  
2                  $196,857      NaN  
3                $6,090,172      NaN  
4               $47,326,473      NaN
```

Your original solution:

```
data = []
#find first table
tab = soup.select("table")[0]
#find all tr elements
rows = tab.find_all(['tr'])
#loop anf find all td
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    #parse text
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    #[:-1] remove last column
    data.append(cols[:-1])

cols = ['Release_Date','Movie_Name','Genre','Production_Budget','DomesticBox']
#[2:] remove first 2 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns = cols)
print (df.head())
  Release_Date     Movie_Name   Genre Production_Budget  DomesticBox
0    January 6     BloodRayne  Action       $25,000,000   $2,405,420
1                    Fateless   Drama       $12,000,000     $196,857
2               Grandma's Boy  Comedy        $5,000,000   $6,090,172
3                      Hostel  Horror        $4,800,000  $47,326,473
4               Kill the Poor                                     $0
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Out of curiosity, do you know why my original code only returned the first line?

Comment: I think you need loop in td elements, not in table, because table is only one.

Comment: That's perfect - thank you for helping me. It's greatly appreciated and it worked perfectly. Problem solved :)

Comment: Quick question - why do you put [0] at the end in the tab variable?

Comment: because `soup.select("table")` return list of all possible tables in webpage. So in this webpage it return one element list and select first value of list is by `[0]`

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.